# How to navigate to Home page from Application logo?

Tags: html, angular, navigation, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate. I want to navigate to Home page when I click on Application logo. But I cannot find any method to change its click behavior.

**topbar.component.html**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Application Name</a>
```

I want a similar behavior like when you click on side menu items.

**sidebar-nav.component.ts**

```
new MenuItem(this.l("HomePage"), "", "home", "/app/home")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asp-controller` and `asp-action` are [Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

For an Angular component, use the [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description) attribute:

```html
<a routerLink="/app/home" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Application Name</a>
```

Comment: Will be fixed in template v3.8: [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template#245](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/245)